# How to get the range of string for attributed string?

Tags: ios, swift, range, nsattributedstring, swift4

I have string as `2/42`. Here 2 & 42 is dynamic.Now I want to set `/42` as superscript of string. I am not able to find out the range of `/42`. please tell me how do i find out the range in swift?

Comment: `NSRegularExpression`, `NSScanner`, `rangeOf` (if find the `/`) is clearly enough...

Answer (score 13):

Mutable string of attributed string has functionality to find of range of specific string.

Try this and see (Swift 4):

```
let stringValue = "2/42"
let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
let range: NSRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: "/42", options: .caseInsensitive)
print("range - \(range)")
```

> **Result:** 
>   
> range - {1, 3}

Ref Snapshot:

[image]